# Android: SurfaceView OnClick "Unfortunately, .....stop.."

Tags: android

I want to implement the bitmap to surfaceview and try to edit the image by button when click it.  But there is a problem. All are correct when I run it on the emulator, until press the button. "Unfortunately, .....stop.." showed up on the screen and program was forced to shut down.  Please help me to figure it out. Thank you very much.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_effect_ver1);

    SurfaceView surfaceView01 = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surfaceView1);
    btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    btn3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);

    res = getResources();
    bmpDraw =(BitmapDrawable) res.getDrawable(R.drawable.images);
    bmp =bmpDraw.getBitmap();
```

I want to remove this Onclick method. But how could I declare surfaceView = (SurfaceView)v; without View v, and move this one to Oncreat?

```
    surfaceView01.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            surfaceView = (SurfaceView)v;

            canvas = surfaceView.getHolder().lockCanvas();
            Paint paint =new Paint();

            canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);

            canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, 50, 150, paint);
            surfaceView.getHolder().unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
        }
    });
```

and here is the logcat

```
12-17 17:24:26.490: E/AndroidRuntime(583): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-17 17:24:26.490: E/AndroidRuntime(583): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.Button cannot be cast to android.view.SurfaceView
12-17 17:24:26.490: E/AndroidRuntime(583):  at com.example.effect_ver1.Effect_ver1$2.onClick(Effect_ver1.java:61)
12-17 17:24:26.490: E/AndroidRuntime(583):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3480)
12-17 17:24:26.490: E/AndroidRuntime(583):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:13983)
12-17 17:24:26.490: E/AndroidRuntime(583):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
12-17 17:24:26.490: E/AndroidRuntime(583):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-17 17:24:26.490: E/AndroidRuntime(583):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-17 17:24:26.490: E/AndroidRuntime(583):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
12-17 17:24:26.490: E/AndroidRuntime(583):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-17 17:24:26.490: E/AndroidRuntime(583):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-17 17:24:26.490: E/AndroidRuntime(583):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
12-17 17:24:26.490: E/AndroidRuntime(583):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
12-17 17:24:26.490: E/AndroidRuntime(583):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Are `surfaceView1` and `button1` unique to the layout `activity_effect_ver1`? Or do you reuse those names in other layouts?

Answer (score 2):

The View v in the button click listener is referring to the view of the Button not the SurfaceView. Remove `surfaceView = (SurfaceView)v;` and change all references of `surfaceView` to `surfaceView01`

The following should work for you but I don't have a way of testing it right now.

```
private SurfaceView surfaceView01;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_effect_ver1);

    surfaceView01 = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surfaceView1);
    btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    btn3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);

    res = getResources();
    bmpDraw =(BitmapDrawable) res.getDrawable(R.drawable.images);
    bmp =bmpDraw.getBitmap();


    canvas = surfaceView01 .getHolder().lockCanvas();
    Paint paint =new Paint();

    canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, 50, 150, paint);
    surfaceView01 .getHolder().unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
}
```

Comment: I retry your method and the problem was solved. Thank you. But if I want to get surfaceview and show the image without clicking the surfaceview, how do I revise it?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. You don't need the `surfaceView01.setOnClickListener` if thats what you mean. Just remove the method and leave the code inside the `public void onClick(View v) {}` just get rid of the surfaceView  reference and use the surfaceView01 instead. Also, you may want to make the surfaceView01 a class variable so it can be referenced outside of the onCreate method.

Comment: I revised my code as you said. And it works. But, if I want to show my image without click on the surfaceview, how do I declare the surfaceView = (SurfaceView)v in the onCreate method, cause there is no view inside.

Answer (score 0):

In your second click listener, you are casting the target of the click to SurfaceView. The target of that click is the button you added the listener to. That is, it is a Button. A button cannot be casted into SurfaceView, hence the ClassCastException.

Extra tip: read the stacktrace, look at the line number in your class (61 in this case) and look for what could possibly cause a ClassCastException. In your case, line 61 contains a cast. It indicates you that `v` is not a SurfaceView, but a Button. You should at this point be able to connect the dots and relate that Button to the Button btn1 used right before.

You probably want to use surfaceView01 instead. You can either make it final or make it a class member to access it directly from within both click listeners.